# Why do Clean Architectures typically split the implementation between Repository and DataSoruce?

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

In most of the examples that illustrate Clean Architecture, the implementation of the repository and the actual interface (which communicates with the repository containing its data) are separated in dependencies, as shown in the code below.

```kotlin
// Retrofit
interface MyApi {
   @GET("somePath")
   fun getSome() : SomeResponse
}

// Room
@Dao
interface MyDao {
   @Query("select * from mytable")
   fun getSome() : List<SomeEntity>
}

// 1. This is how most examples describe the configuration of a repository.
interface RemoteDataSource {
   fun getSome() : SomeResponse
}
interface LocalDataSource {
   fun getSome() : List<SomeEntity>
}

// instance inject by hilt
class RemoteDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val api : MyApi) : RemoteDataSource {
    override fun getSome() = api.getSome()
}

// instance inject by hilt
class LocalDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val dao : MyDao) : LocalDataSource {
    override fun getSome() = dao.getSome()
}

// instance inject by hilt
class MyRepositoryImpl @Inject (private val remote : RemoteDataSource, private val local : LocalDataSource) : MyRepository {
   override mySomeGetFunction() {
      return MySomeEntity(entity1 = remote.getSome().data, entity2 = local.getSome().data)
   }
}


// 2. why not inline???
// instance inject by hilt
class MyRepositoryImpl @Inject (private val api : MyApi, private val dao : MyDao) : MyRepository {
   override mySomeGetFunction() {
      return MySomeEntity(entity1 = api.getSome().data, entity2 = dao.getSome().data)
   }
}
```

Already they are Interface. Even though they are weakly dependent types whose injections can be swapped at will depending on build flavor, many examples wrap them once more as DataSource and simply bypass them in their implementations.

Is there any upfront reason to do this? I tried to find a lot of references, but I didn't see anything about Repository and DataSource.

Comment: I think you did not ask your question clearly. In some of your sentences you've used the word "Repository" instead of "DataSource". Please review your question carefully and edit it, then I'll try to help you find the answer.

Comment: @MohammadFallah I thought the title of the question was wrong, so I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding at the level of some notions or may be the question is not well clear.

Repository is a pattern used to interact with external data source most of time from a database.
It does not depend on Clean Architecture.
I suggest to check this question where I describe more about Repository pros and cons here
[Clean architecture and repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479513/clean-architecture-and-repositories/77512042#77512042)

From Clean Architecture point of vue:
You need to separate any dependency of the project and reduce its change impact on your design as possible as you can.
Most of the time these dependencies are external source like:

- Your database: (Input Dependency)
  Here you may use Repository to interact with it or may other pattern like pure datalayer...
  The most important thing is that your project should only recognize interfaces of this routines not implementation.
  You need to model a Domain/Business layer that only depend on IClientRepository for exemple and not see or know about the ClientRepository implementation.
- An Api: we can have two cases here:

  - An Api that you will consume (**Input Dependency**). It will be like your layer that interact with your database. Instead of database connection it will http connection...
  - An Api that you will expose (**Output Dependency**)
- There are other dependencies like Frameworks. I'm going to bypass them here.

So your core domain/project will be the Kernel of your design.

It interact with many interfaces that represent the Input Dependencies (the Domain use the dependency interface like IClientRepository or IPaymentApiClient).

And it expose also their interfaces for the Output Dependencies (your Api that expose the domain features by using its interfaces, most of the time we call this layer Application layer).

Don't hesitate to write comments for more clarification.